# Unable to open Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 13.10, software-center

I have got Ubuntu 13.10 to my old laptop. I wanted to look for apps and stuff in Software Center. So I opened it & it opens slowly and then just closed soon after. I do not see any reason nor an error.. Just closing suddenly. What could be the problem?

Comment: what was the output of `software-center`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstall it?

If not try this

```
sudo apt-get purge software-center

sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Hope it works.